# What's the easiest way to sync music to my phone?

Tags: sync, 6.0-marshmallow, file-system

I'm now on CM13 (Android 6) and `rsync`ing in will not work due to permission errors (and the `sudo` command doesn't exist) So I ask you, are there any programs to sync my music across? I don't want to use services that require me to upload it and then download it again due to bandwidth and speed issues.

I have also tried adb-sync but it just errors out (as is expected with adb!).

Comment: You can use `su -c 'command'` rather than `sudo command`.

Comment: It still didn't work, I had tried that before posting. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bittorrent Sync to copy the music folder on your computer to your phone. The whole thing will complete on your local network (as long as you don't leave it!). I recommend Bittorrent Sync assuming your local network's speed isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: there's no `sudo` on Android, just `su`. And for using ADB as root the daemon on the Android device must run in "insecure mode" (i.e. as root, e.g. using Chainfire's "insecure adbd" app).

If you don't want to go that way, there are easier alternatives which you can e.g. find in my list on [Synchronizing Files and Folders](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync). I'd recommend taking a look at [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite), which I use myself (just in the [paid variant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full)). Supports a plethora of protocols for all kind of systems (including SFTP/SCP to work with Linux machines, and CIFS/SMB for Windows). Lets you define folder pairs to sync. You can even setup a scheduler for it, and tell it to only sync when you're connected to your home WiFi. And more (e.g. cloud, which you stated you don't want ;)

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an SSH server on Android 6.0 is fairly easy and works well with rsync. I installed SSHDroid. You need to use the SD:/Android/data/com.* path relevant to the app for the files you are syncing however.